# Unauthorized Facebook Business Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I need to take down a Facebook business page that was made by someone not associated with this business. I'm the marketing director for the company and need to make a new page for my client. I don't have a password for the existing page.

Answer (score 2):

Report the page https://www.facebook.com/help/355811251195044

Contact Facebook's customer support. They will be able to assist with authenticating the page, or in your particular case take down the page which is acting as the business you represent.